# What could 何も無かったり、有ったり mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, expressions

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what this means (bolded):

> どこに行くんですか？
>
> あ。。。森。。。ですか。。。
> 森の中、そこだけは
> **何も無かったり、有ったり**
> 過去の遺物の集積場
> 「ここにやがてつまれるのかな？」

What does 何も無かったり、あったり mean?

This is from a song.

Comment: Is that the entire sentence?

Comment: Is this from a poem, a song or a tweet? Please include the whole context. Usually a rhetorical expression like this comes with a hint in sentences surrounding it.

Comment: Apparently the text comes from here https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66398/7810 but I'm not sure what OP means by "Since it's using ~tari, is the fact that it's past tense relevant here?"

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be from [初音ミクの終焉](https://www5.atwiki.jp/hmiku/pages/346.html).

It's not past tense (ta-form), but it's [**tari-form**](http://maggiesensei.com/2013/09/29/how-to-use-%E3%80%9C%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8Atari-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6tarishite/) used to list two or more verbs [and i-adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29317/5010). So 「何も無かったり、有ったり」 roughly means "sometimes there is nothing, sometimes there is something" or "there may or may not be something".

Comment: Another question: is the speaker doubting whether 過去の遺物の集積場 exists? As in, does the sentence mean, there might/might not be a place where relics of the past accumulate? EDIT: My bad, they're doubting what's in the forest, like you said

Comment: @kumichan The subject of ある/ない is 何 ("something"), not 集積場.